# How do I animate selected card have flip and pop-out effect both at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am preparing a demo for a card game in web with jquery effects

I have done with swap effect but when the user selects the card on the time I have to do an effect like the card is flipping and pop-out out too same time.

[image]

This is how it's showing when I click any card it should flip and pop-out in the center with overlay.

I have tried mflip plugin of jquery but can't pop out the card at the same time.

How do I animate selected card to have a flip and pop-out effect both at the same time?

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  
  var swapperarray = [];
            swapperarray[0] = ['div_3', 'div_1'];
            swapperarray[1] = ['div_3', 'div_4'];
            swapperarray[2] = ['div_7', 'div_8'];
            swapperarray[3] = ['div_9', 'div_2'];
            swapperarray[4] = ['div_2', 'div_7'];
            swapperarray[5] = ['div_5', 'div_6'];
            swapperarray[6] = ['div_8', 'div_7'];
            swapperarray[7] = ['div_1', 'div_4'];
            swapperarray[8] = ['div_6', 'div_9'];
            swapperarray[9] = ['div_3', 'div_7'];
            
           $('#'+swapperarray[0][0]).swap(createOptions(swapperarray))
});
 function createOptions(swapperarray){
       var obj = {};
   
      if(swapperarray.length > 1){
        var pair = swapperarray.shift();
        obj.target = pair[1];
        obj.opacity = "1";
        obj.speed = 600;
        obj.callback = function (){ $('#'+swapperarray[0][0]).swap(createOptions(swapperarray)) }
      }
      else 
   {
        var pair = swapperarray.shift()
        obj.target = pair[1]
        obj.opacity = "1"
        obj.speed = 600
      }
   if(swapperarray.length == 0)
   {
    $('.cards').addClass("Flipper");
    $('.cards').addClass("FlipperShadow");
    $('.overlay').hide();
    ShadowStarter()
    
   }
      return obj;
   
    }
function ShadowStarter()
{
 setInterval(function ()
 {
  $('.Flipper').toggleClass("FlipperShadow");
 },1000)
}
$(document).ready(function ()
{
 $('body').on("click",'.Flipper',function ()
 {
  
  $('.Flipper').removeClass("Flipper");
  $('.FlipperShadow').removeClass("FlipperShadow");
  var leftclass = $(this).attr('id');
  //$(this).addClass("popout");
 });
 $(".cards").flip();




});
```

```css
.cards {
 width:120px;
 height:160px;
 border:1px solid #1d174f;
 border-radius:5px;
 float:left;
 margin:5px;
 text-align:center;
 padding:5px;
}
.cards img
{
 width:90%;
 margin-top:10%;
}
.cards:hover
{
 cursor:pointer;
}
.Blocks
{
   display: block;
    width: 428px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
  clear:both;
}
.actionbar
{
 clear:both;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
}



.FlipperShadow {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 11px 0px #1d174f;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* Transition to a bigger shadow on hover */
.FlipperShadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

/* The fast way */
.FlipperShadow {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 11px 0px #1d174f;
}

/* Pre-render the bigger shadow, but hide it */
.FlipperShadow::after {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* Transition to showing the bigger shadow on hover */
.FlipperShadow:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.FlipperShadow
{
 /*box-shadow: 0px 2px 11px 0px #1d174f;*/
}
.clearfix
{
 clear:both;
}

.overlay
{
  width: 428px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #0020;
  z-index: 9999;
 
}
.popout 
{
  animation: popout 1s ease;
  -webkit-animation: popout 1s ease;
}
@keyframes popout {
  from{transform:scale(0)}
  80%{transform:scale(1.2)}
  to{transform:scale(1)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes popout {
  from{-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
  80%{-webkit-transform:scale(1.2)}
  to{-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://sgmobilepos.com/cardgame/js/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://sgmobilepos.com/cardgame/js/jquery-swapsies.js"></script>
<div class="Blocks">
 <div class="overlay"></div> 
  <div class="cards" id="div_1">
   <div class="front"><img src="1.png"></div>
   <div class="back">Ans is here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards" id="div_2">
   <div class="front"><img src="1.png"></div>
   <div class="back">Ans is here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards" id="div_3">
   <div class="front"><img src="1.png"></div>
   <div class="back">Ans is here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards" id="div_4">
   <div class="front"><img src="1.png"></div>
   <div class="back">Ans is here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards" id="div_5">
   <div class="front"><img src="1.png"></div>
   <div class="back">Ans is here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards" id="div_6"
   ><div class="front"><img src="1.png"></div>
   <div class="back">Ans is here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards" id="div_7">
   <div class="front"><img src="1.png"></div>
   <div class="back">Ans is here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards" id="div_8">
   <div class="front"><img src="1.png"></div>
   <div class="back">Ans is here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards" id="div_9">
   <div class="front"><img src="1.png"></div>
   <div class="back">Ans is here</div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n44ofk4y/26/ this is the fiddle link

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: @WebDevBooster added